# How can I insert an array of variable into a database individually in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, insert

How can i insert the array into the database individually, It's displaying error. I want to insert them all at once... sometimes the array may be more the 3, 5 or 10.

```
$roll_num = '111,222,333';
$rollnum = explode(",",$roll_num);

$sql ="INSERT INTO eyfstb(specialnum)  VALUES('$rollnum[]')";

if($db->query($sql)== TRUE){
    echo "true";
}else{
     echo "false";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Insert it Dynamically to your `Database` and this will fix your problem. :D

```
  $roll_num = '111,222,333';
  $rollnum_arr = explode(",",$roll_num);

  for($x = 0; $x < count($rollnum_arr); $x++){
      $sql ="INSERT INTO eyfstb(specialnum)  VALUES(".$rollnum_arr[$x].")";
  }

  if($db->query($sql) == TRUE){
      echo "true";
  }else{
      echo "false";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The explode function converts your array into a multiple index variables, so regarding your question, it should be:

```
$roll_num = '111,222,333';
$rollnum = explode(",",$roll_num);

$sql ="INSERT INTO eyfstb(specialnum)  VALUES('$rollnum[0]')";

if($db->query($sql)== TRUE){
    echo "true";
}else{
     echo "false";
}
```

If you want to insert all of them, you could either store it as a JSON in your table, or create additional columns.

Comment: I want to insert them all at once... sometimes the array may be more the 3, 5 or 10.

Comment: To fix your problem you need to use a `loop` function so that you can insert dynamically to your `Database`. Pls, take a look to my answer above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to insert a new row for each array cell. To do so, I would recommend:

```
$roll_num = '111,222,333';
$rollnum = explode(",", $roll_num);

$sql = "INSERT INTO eyfstb(specialnum) VALUES('" . implode("'),('", $rollnum) . "')";
```

That will produce the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO eyfstb(specialnum) VALUES('111'),('222'),('333')
```

And will be more efficient than looping and inserting every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Firt of all, your $roll_num variable is not an array.
And the explode function will split your string by a string as it said here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

For that you could build your array whith your values inside like:

```
$roll_num = array('111', '222','333');
```

And INSERT INTO thanks to a loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($roll_num); $i++) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO eyfstb(specialnum)  VALUES(" . $roll_num[$i] . ")";
    $db->query($sql);
    $db->execute();

}
```

It should work :)